# Drawing charts in Android

Tags: android

When I  trying to draw a chart on android I found this
[here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/creating-charts-with-droidcharts-for-android/)

but there is an error when import "import net.droidsolutions.droidcharts.awt.Rectangle2D;"
it says "The import net cannot be resolved"
what should I do?

Comment: have you added to the build path the external jar?

Comment: Did you include the jar library "DroidCharts.jar" into you project via class path/build path or sth.?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of free and paid charts available for android.. I listed some of them in my previous answer.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10716564/304270